# How to re-connect to an existing JMS durable subscriber without knowing the JMS selector

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I'm new to JMS and am trying to setup Apache Active MQ for a messaging application as an alternative to Azure Service Bus that I'm very familiar with. I would like to setup topics and durable subscribers as and administrative task, and would like the runtime process to consume messages from those existing durable subscriber only based upon its name and, possibly, client id.

How do I retrieve an existing durable subscriber, without knowing the selector?
All the documentation and the samples I've read show that the only way to consume a message is to call the `session.createDurableSubscriber()` method.

Additionaly, I prefer to use the AMQP abstraction over JMS. So I found the following code to retrieve an existing subscriber:

```
    public static ReceiverLink RecoverDurableSource(Session session, string topicPath, string subscriptionName)
    {
        Source recovered = null;

        using (var attached = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            void OnAttached(ILink link, Attach Attach)
            {
                recovered = (Source)Attach.Source;
                attached.Set();
            }

            ReceiverLink receiver = null;
            try
            {
                receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, subscriptionName, (Source)null, OnAttached);

                if (!attached.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
                    return null;

                CloseReceiverLink(receiver);

                return recovered != null
                        ? new ReceiverLink(session, subscriptionName, recovered, null)
                        : null
                    ;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (recovered == null)
                    CloseReceiverLink(receiver);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void CloseReceiverLink(ReceiverLink receiver)
    {
        if (receiver == null)
            return;

        if (receiver.Error == null || Equals(receiver.Error.Condition, new Symbol("amqp:not-found")))
            receiver.Close();
    }
```

However, this code has the nasty side effect to re-create and default durable subscriber (manifested in this code by the `ReceiverLink` object) with the same name and then, if it exists, re-creating it with the correct `Source`object.

But this may disrupt the reception of messages at the time this method is called.